# How are bounties cancelled?

Tags: support, bounty

How is a bounty canceled when the person is asking for nonsensical details about a question that has been clearly asked and answered?
[Why do some RJ45 plugs have the lock release clip under a rubber cover?](https://superuser.com/questions/681312/why-do-some-rj45-plugs-have-the-lock-release-clip-under-a-rubber-cover)
If the user is asking a question that isn't the same as the question in question, shouldn't they be required to formulate their own question?

Answer (score 6):

When another user starts a bounty on an existing question they may think it already asked the question well enough to not have to create a duplicate or their own version. Bounties can be used to lure out other answers, or answers that address the note left by the bounty drop.

Only moderators can cancel a bounty.

If a user wants to throw a bounty onto something that has no reason to, that's their concern.

If the question needs to be migrated, a moderator will cancel the bounty before doing so.

If the question otherwise needs to be simply closed, the bounty may be either allowed to run out or cancelled immediately.

Comment: I guess that's the thing.  They're not asking a similar or identical question along the same lines, they're asking something else entirely that should be its own question and not a bounty on an existing asked-and-answered question.

Comment: Further, it looks like the question is taking collateral downvote damage because the bounty was attached.  All the user has done is harm, and no good.